# Trying to re-upload images using an importer but it's still detecting images that have been deleted

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, image

I used a **wordpress** plugin to download post images into my uploads folder.

It didn't work as expected the first time so I deleted my images.

Using it again it still detects images that are no longer in my uploads folder but still must be associated with my post somehow.

I've cleaned up my wp_postmeta but it's detecting these images, I'm not sure which other tables they would be in.

I am not very mysql savvy, but is there a query I could run comparing my uploads library with whichever table column is holding this image data?

Or something that detects orphaned image links, links without an actual image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a plugin such as `search and replace` to first do a find on the image name. It will check against the database to find all instances of whatever the image name is.

Link to plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/